# Layer and Buffer Creator - custom method

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, spatial-analyst, buffer

I am trying to make a script function that creates layers for further use to buffer the layer. My code doesn't give me any error but neither any buffered layer.

My code is below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = True
mxd_path = r"C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Projekt.mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)

if arcpy.Exists("Tennis_layer"):
    arcpy.management.Delete("Tennis_layer")


#Shapefiles
tennis = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Tennis'
pulka = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Pulka_val.shp'
rest = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Restuarants.shp'
out_path = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\outputs.gdb'

def make_layer(path_shp, layername):
    return arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path_shp,layername)

tennis_lyr = make_layer(tennis, "Tennis_layer")

def buffer(layer, out_layer,radius):
    try:
        in_featureclass = layer
        out_feautreclass = out_layer
        bufferDistance = radius
        return (arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_featureclass, out_feautreclass, bufferDistance + 'Meters'))

        # Report a success message
        arcpy.AddMessage("All done!")
    except:
        arcpy.AddError("Could not complete the buffer")
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())



tennis_buff = buffer(tennis_lyr,'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\outputs.gdb\Tennis_buff.shp', 1000 )
print tennis_buff
```

Comment: arcpy.env.workspace should be a path to a folder, or geodatabase. See https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/current-workspace.htm and get familiar with how it works. You are not using an mxd in the workflow so accessing in your code is not needed. Checking for existing Tennis_Layer will work if you set the env.workspace path where it needs to look for this feature lass.

Comment: Your #Shapefiles section, you are using a geodatabase by the looks of it so dont put .shp at the end of your layer names. Shapefiles go in a folder, feature classes into a geodatabase. You dont need to MakeFeatureLayer before buffering. Use docs for guidance https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm no need to make a buffer function as its already a function just wrap it in your try/except.

Comment: You dont require the following because you dont use them in your script; from arcpy import env; from arcpy.sa import *; import os.